# How add seaborn plots to subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I try to create subplots and add there seaborn plots but results are empty and I just got all the results as unique plots after subplots figure.

I use that code

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(40, 20), sharey=True, dpi=160)

cols = [color for name, color in mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.items()]
cols = [cols[2]] + [cols[7]] + cols[9:12] + cols[14:18] + cols[19:]

companies = data['name'].value_counts()[:6].index

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    company_data = data[data['name'] == companies[i]]

    data_viz = company_data.groupby(['year', 'lda_cluster']).agg({'Publication Number': 'count'}).reset_index()

    sns.catplot(data=data_viz, x='year', y='Publication Number', hue='lda_cluster', 
            ax=ax, kind='bar', height=10, aspect=1.5)
    ax.set_title(f'{companies[i]}')

plt.show()
```

And it's my result

[image]
[image]
etc

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried using sns.set()?

Comment: @Zephyrus no, how can I use it here?

Answer (score 0):

`sns.catplot` returns a FacetGrid, which is a figure on it's own. You haven't provided any example data but I think you can achieve what you are aiming for using `kind="count"`

```py
companies = list(data["name"].value_counts().nlargest(6).index)

g = sns.catplot(
    x="year",
    col="name",
    col_wrap=3,
    data=data[data["name"].isin(companies)],
    kind="count",
    height=10,
    aspect=1.5,
)

g.set_axis_labels(y_var="Publication Number")
g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}")
```